# Python PyODBC and SQL Server encoding issue

Tags: python, sql-server, character-encoding, pyodbc

I have json file with values, that have characters like 'č', 'ė', etc. I want to insert those values to SQL Server database, but values I see in database are 'Ä' instead of 'č', 'Ä—' instead of 'ė', 'ÄŒ' instead of 'Č', etc. How should I deal with this problem?

I tried things, that were on StackOverflow and pyodbc wiki, like:

```
self.connection.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
self.connection.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
self.connection.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')
```

(also tried latin1 encoding, because I saw somewhere, that it could help).

I tried adding charset to connection string:

```
connection_string = (
    f'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}};'
    f'SERVER={server};'
    f'DATABASE={database};'
    'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    'Encrypt=no;'
    'CHARSET=UTF-8;'
)
```

But nothing solved my problem.

This is how I read my file:

```
def read_values(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        return json.load(file)
```

This is how I insert my data:

```
def insert(self, table_name: str, column_values: dict):
    columns = ', '.join(column_values.keys())
    values = ', '.join([f"'{value}'" for value in column_values.values()])

    query = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} ({columns}) VALUES ({values})"
    print(query)

    try:
        cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        cursor.execute("SELECT @@IDENTITY AS ID;")
        last_inserted_id = cursor.fetchone()[0]
        self.connection.commit()
        print("Data inserted successfully.")
        return last_inserted_id
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error inserting data: {e}")
    finally:
        cursor.close()
```

`print(query)` prints the right query, with right characters.

If I write the right characters directly into the database with my keyboard, everything works fine.

Comment: What collation is your database in? If it's *not* UTF-8 then that behaviour is expected.

Comment: Your statement also looks concerningly open to injection attacks , on the table name, column names, *and* the data.

Comment: @ThomA SSMS shows that my collation is 'Latin1_General_CI_AS', which as I understand is not UTF-8 (right? I am not very educated on this), but then why if I put those characters directly into database, or use database dump in query to insert all my previous data, it works fine? And main question, so I should just use 'Latin1_General_CI_AS_UTF8' collation? That's what I found from google search now. And how to set collation for whole database if I am creating it from migrations with `Update-Database` in Visual Studio Package Manager?

Comment: Unless you want to have issues or know the quirks well, i would avoid utf8 when dealing with sql server. Use nvarchar and it should usually just "work". If you have json, it's probably easier to just pass it as parameter to OPENJSON and do the conversion on SQL Server side.

Comment: If you want to pass UTF-8 data to the database (which you imply you do), then yes, your database should also be collated as UTF-8. Otherwise, as mentioned, what you get is expected. using your data as an example the `binary` value for `č` as a UTF-8 is 0xC48D, *however*, in ASCII `0xC48D` would be `Ä` (there is a second unprintable character there), which *is* what you are getting in your environment. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qdlMjFFC) The alternative would be to use `nvarchar` in your database, *not* `varchar`. Personally I'd just work with `nvarchar` data.

Answer (score 3):

##### Issue 1: Don't use `.setencoding()` and `.setdecoding()` for SQL Server.

As mentioned in the [pyodbc wiki entry for SQL Server](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Unicode#microsoft-sql-server), they are not necessary.

##### Issue 2: Don't use string formatting (a.k.a. dynamic SQL) to inject column *values* into an SQL statement.

The real problem you are having is that you are constructing an INSERT statement that looks something like this:

```py
print(query)
# INSERT INTO so78154305 (firstname) VALUES ('Renée')
```

SQL Server uses `'string'` for varchar and `N'string'` for nvarchar, so a Unicode literal should be `N'Renée'`.

But that would still be bad form. Use a parameterized query instead. For example

```py
columns = ', '.join([f"[{key}]" for key in column_values.keys()])
placeholders = ', '.join("?" * len(column_values.values()))

query = f"INSERT INTO [{table_name}] ({columns}) VALUES ({placeholders})"
print(query)
# INSERT INTO [so78154305] ([firstname], [active]) VALUES (?, ?)

cursor.execute(query, tuple(column_values.values()))
```